# How to calculate Bloom filter percentage

Tags: algorithm, hadoop

I am going through [Hadoop In Action](http://www.manning.com/lam/) and came across explanation on `Bloom Filter`, where it says:

> The false positive rate is approximated by the equation

```
(1 – exp(-kn/m))k
```

> where k is the number of hash functions used, m is the
>   number of bits used to store the Bloom filter, and n is the number of
>   elements to be added to the Bloom filter. In practice, m and n are
>   determined by the requirement of the system, and therefore, k is
>   chosen to minimize the false positive rate given m and n, which (after
>   a little calculus) is

```
k = ln(2) * (m/n) ≈ 0.7 * (m/n)
```

> The false
>   positive rate with the given k is 0.6185m/n, and k has to be an
>   integer. The false positive rate will only be an approximation. From a
>   design point of view, one should think in terms of (m/n), number of
>   bits per element, rather than m alone. For example, we have to store a
>   set containing ten million URLs (n=10,000,000). Allocat­ ing 8 bits
>   per URL (m/n=8) will require a 10 MB Bloom filter (m = 80,000,000
>   bits). This Bloom filter will have a false positive rate of (0.6185)8,
>   or about 2 percent. If we were to implement the Set class by storing
>   the raw URLs, and let’s say the average URL length was 100 bytes, we
>   would have to use 1 GB. Bloom filter has shrunk the storage
>   requirement by 2 orders of magnitude at the expense of only a 2
>   percent false positive rate! A slight increase in storage allocated to
>   the Bloom filter will reduce the false posi­ tive rate further. At 10
>   bits per URL, the Bloom filter will take up 12.5 MB and have a false
>   positive rate of only 0.8 percent.

So here it says that the the false positive rate is 0.6185*8 which is 4.948 but how the document says that it is approximately 2%? Can someone please help me how the percentage is calcluated?

**Detailed explanation based on David's response:**

Based on explanation in book:

```
n = 10,000,000 = 1e7

m/n = 8 which means m = 8*n

k = ln(2) * (m/n), Value of ln(2) is 0.693 = 0.7, so value of k = 0.7 * (m/n)
```

Now coming to my expression:

```
 (1 – exp^(-kn/m))^k = (1 - exp^(-0.7))^(0.7*8) = (1 - 0.4965)^(5.6) = (0.5034)^(5.6) = 0.0214 (Here ^ represents power)
```

To calculate percentage, we have to multiply with 100.

So the percentage is `0.0214*100 = 2%`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct formula is

```
                k
(1 – exp(-kn/m)) ,
```

taking the parenthesized expression to the power k instead of multiplying by k. The approximation is mostly to assume that the value of each cell of the Bloom filter is independent (with a little bit of error from writing exp instead of the true single-cell probability); the false positive rate is the probability that k cells all have been marked.

Here is how to compute the false positive probability for the given example.

```
>>> from math import *
>>> n = 1e7
>>> m = 8*n
>>> k = log(2) * (m/n)
>>> (1 - exp(-k*n/m)) ** k
0.021415847120683718
```

To convert the probability to a percentage, multiply by 100.

```
>>> 100*_
2.1415847120683718
```

Comment: Thanks for responding, also can you please tell me how the percentage is calculated?

Comment: Can you please add comments on how you have achieved the result. I am not getting how `n=1e7` and `m=8*n` and remaining lines of your updated answer. Sorry for troubling you.

Comment: @user3181365 `1e7` is short for 10,000,000. I'm setting `m = 8*n` by multiplying both sides of the equation m/n = 8 by n.

Comment: Thanks David for taking time to clarify my question.